# Optimization on $X^TX$ with all positive entries

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Suppose I have an algorithm $\mathit{A}$ that can solve the optimization problem over certain functions $g: Sym(n) \to \mathbb{R}$. Now given $g$, let $f: \mathbb{R}^{k ,n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be another function such that $f(X) = g(X^TX)$, how can I solve the following problem?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X \in \mathbb{R}^{k, n}}{\text{minimize}} & \displaystyle f(X) \\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle X \geq \bf{0}\end{array}$$

suppose I also know the basic info of $g$ like its gradient, hessian, and also that $g$ is sufficiently nice (in a sense that the program is solvable).

Comment: So you can get the symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $M$ that satisfies your optimization and now you just need to find a positive $k \times n$ matrix $X$ such that $X^T X = M$? If so, I don't get what this has to do with optimization. But if you don't have $M$, then I don't get what the fact that you have an algorithm to get $M$ gets you.

Comment: The thing is that not every symmetric matrix can be factored into the product of a positive matrix, and to check if a matrix is "completely positive" (i.e. has such factorization) is NP-hard. The algorithm can find the global minimum on the space of the symmetric matrix but not with the extra constraint.